# JButtons re-enable themselves after being disabled

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

I have an array of JButtons which form a keypad interface. After six numbers are entered I want to disable the keypad so that no further numbers can be entered by the user.

I have written the code and the buttons do disable until the mouse hovers above any of them, then the buttons seem to re-enable themselves and run actionEvents added to them.

The full code is available [here](http://refactormycode.com/codes/1260-jbuttons-re-enable-themselves-when-hovered-over).

Possible things that I think are wrong.

1. There is some sort of MouseListener which is ignoring when I set  `button.setEnabled(false);`
2. I haven't separated attributes from the `buildGUI();` correctly, I only did this anyway so that the inner class could access them.
3. Possibly something to do with the `gridLayout` as disabling the buttons *seems* to work for my `services` JPanel buttons.

Comment: I've downloaded and run your code and can't recreate the issue you describe.

Comment: same here. That code is OK, just missing the `main` method. Can you post the .class file?

Comment: I've added the class files here: http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/100415023349-50246.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in how you instantiated your Frame (`CashMachine`), not (directly) with its implementation.

You are calling `buildGUI` twice, one in the object's constructor, and then in the `Driver` class that instantiates the object. As a result, you are creating (and laying out) *two* sets of buttons.

When the buttons of the first set were eventually disabled, your mousing activity was revealing the second set of buttons. And a flaw in your ActionListener implementation can cause `inputCount` to take on values greater than 6, so buttons in the second set were not eventually disabled like those from the first set.

`buildGUI` should be private; it should be called in the CashMachine constructor, and not by your `Driver` class.

Conversely, in my opinion, `CashMachine.setVisible` should be called by the `Driver` class, and not by the `CashMachine` constructor.

Comment: I've tested the code on 2 machines (XP, Windows 7) using NetBeans 6.8 and in the command line on Java 1.6.0_18 b07.

Here is a screenshot after I have hovered over serveral buttons:
http://imgur.com/Mqq1D.png

Comment: If you could make the compiled program downloadable from somewhere, we could run/decompile it to look for other causes.

Comment: Thanks I have added a comment to the parent with a link to the class files.

Comment: Problem reproduced. See my revised answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The code works just fine I guess.

Answer (score 1):

One possible source of confusion in your program is mixing number keys with control keys, `Clear` and `Enter`. Consider handling number keys separately with a single listener, as suggested in the `NumberButton` class shown below. Then you can handle the `Clear` and `Enter` buttons as desired. Also, using a `List<NumberButton>` makes the enable and disable loops easier.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class KeyPadPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final int MAX = 6;
    private final List<NumberButton> numbers = new ArrayList<NumberButton>();
    private final JTextArea text = new JTextArea(1, MAX);
    private final JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    private final JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");

    public KeyPadPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel display = new JPanel();
        text.setEditable(false);
        display.add(text);
        this.add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel pad = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            NumberButton n = new NumberButton(i);
            numbers.add(n);
            if (i > 0) {
                pad.add(n);
            }
        }
        pad.add(clear);
        pad.add(numbers.get(0));
        pad.add(enter);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        enter.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(pad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        text.setText("");
        enableButtons();
    }

    private void enableButtons() {
        for (NumberButton n : numbers) {
            n.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void disableButtons() {
        for (NumberButton n : numbers) {
            n.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private class NumberButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

        public NumberButton(int number) {
            super(String.valueOf(number));
            this.addActionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            NumberButton b = (NumberButton) e.getSource();
            if (text.getText().length() < MAX) {
                text.append(b.getText());
            }
            if (text.getText().length() == MAX) {
                disableButtons();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new KeyPadPanel());
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still in the process of Java and haven't started using lists as of yet. However the main purpose of the array was just to place the keys elegantly in the style of a standard ATM.

What imports are required in order to compile the code you have posted?

Comment: Imports added. I've become dependent on the typical IDE's `fix imports` command.

Answer (score 1):

Examining the class files was helpful! The problem is in the Driver class:
the `buildGUI()` method is being called 2 times: once in the constructor of CashMachine and second in the `main` method after calling the constructor.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    CashMachine cashmachine = new CashMachine();
    cashmachine.buildGUI();
}
```

This way you end up with the double number of buttons, that is, a pair of buttons at each position. But only one of each is being disabled.
Just remove the call to `buildGUI` from `main` (or from the constructor).
(I would change `buildGUI` to private as it should not be called from outside the class...)