# mouse listener event

Tags: swing

I have got a program having an array of buttons, each of these button has their mouselistener event.

Now, how can i find which of the buton is clicked through the mouse listener.

Comment: Are you using one mouse listener for all of the buttons? Or put another way, do you have one mouse listener registered with all of the buttons in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to respond to buttons is via an [`ActionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), as discussed in [*How to Use Buttons*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640380/jbuttons-re-enable-themselves-after-being-disabled/2641558#2641558) uses both individual and common listeners to implement a keypad. If you are actually using a [`MouseListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to locate components, [`findComponentAt(int x, int y)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#findComponentAt%28int,%20int%29) may be useful, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733896).