# Get JButton under location

Tags: java, swing

I have many JPanels with buttons inside. I want detect JButton under mouse location on screen.

I get mouse location by

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

and I want check is JButton exist on this location and get this button.

Example:

Button left corner is on screen location (50,50), button size is Width = 100, Height = 50 and mouse is on screen location (70,70).

How can I detect is JButton exist on this location ?

Comment: frame.getlocation+button.getlocation will do it in some way

Comment: Yours answer do not help with anything because I must find this button only using mouse location without any listeners on JButtons

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733896/identifying-swing-component-at-a-particular-screen-coordinate-and-manually-dis

Comment: I try `findComponentAt(...)` but can not find, return null only.

Comment: Second way using `if (window.getMousePosition(true) != null)` do not work too.

Comment: Please explain why you need it. It's possible but with some limitations.

Comment: Having mouse location I need check that is button under mouse, and next when I can check if there is a Button I want change color for it. I do not want  register mouse listeners to all buttons (in my program I have tens of button and it is resource hungry)

Comment: *"I do not want register mouse listeners to all buttons (in my program I have tens of button and it is resource hungry)"* 1) Research 'premature optimization'. This is a classic case. I'd start worrying at 10s **of thousands** of buttons. 2) Don't add mouse listeners to buttons, add an `ActionListener`. 3) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: So as in title - I need to get Button on location (x,y) without adding mouseListeners to all buttons.

Comment: (1-) `I have tens of button and it is resource hungry` - then you have a design problem if you think it is easier to search for the button? How do you then expect to invoke an Action on the button. Do you plan to have 10 of nested if/else statements. That is terrible code to design and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method I use, it may not be the best but it works, you add a listener to your container (JPanel) and you check the position of the cursor when moving, and when the cursor enters Within the limits of a button it checks its index in the container and gives you the ID:

```
List<JButton> btns = new ArrayList<>(); //store all the buttons here for 1 container

//Inside your MouseMove Event of your Panel (only 1)//

   checkPos(evt.x, evt.y);

//////////////////////////////

  private void checkPos(int mousePosX, int mousePosY){

  boolean minX;
  boolean minY;
  boolean maxX;
  boolean maxY;
  for (int i = 0; i < btns.size(); i++) {
    minX = mousePosX >= btns.get(i).getLocation().x;
    minY = mousePosY >= btns.get(i).getLocation().y;
    maxX = mousePosX <= (btns.get(i).getWidth()+ btns.get(i).getLocation().x);
    maxY = mousePosY <= (btns.get(i).getHeight()+ btns.get(i).getLocation().y);

    if (minX && minY && maxX && maxY){  //check if JButton exist on this location

        System.out.println(btns.get(i));  //return the JButton, Can be worked out for more precision
        //OR
        System.out.println("There's a JButton at this Location : " + mousePosX + " - " + mousePosY + " of the screen !");
    }

  }
 }
```

Sorry if I misunderstood the question and good luck !

Comment: This solution almost works. You must change maxX and maxY condition from check button size to location+size :)

Comment: `btns.get(i).getHeigth()` that code would not compile.

Comment: Yes, there should be `btns.get(i).getHeight()` wrong letters :)

Answer (score 2):

> I have tens of button and it is resource hungry

So why do you think this will be resource hungry? Chances are that your buttons will execute the same action so all you need to do is create a single ActionListener that will be shared by each button:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    @Overrid
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        System.out.println(button.getText());
    }
};
```

For a working example of this approach check out: [Attaching A Single Action Listener To All Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436)

> I want detect JButton under mouse location on screen.

For basic Swing knowledge (not needed for this question) you can use the `SwingUtilities` class. It has various method to help you.

1. First you can convert the mouse point to a point relative to your JFrame using the `convertPointFromScreen(...)` method.
2. Then using the above point can use the `getDeepestComponentAt(...)` method to get the component.