# For Java Swing, how can I access the element at (x,y)?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Suppose the declared grid layout:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        JButton[] b = new JButton[9];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            b[i] = new JButton("Button " + i);
            window.add(b[i]);
        }
        
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(300, 300);
        
    }
}
```

Is there a way on how to access the elements (in this case, buttons) in the grid at (x,y)? For example: I want to access window(1,2) so that it would get Button 5.

Comment: Please read the question before being in such a hurry to close the question. This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733896/identifying-swing-component-at-a-particular-screen-coordinate-and-manually-dis. That question solves the problem for finding a component at a `pixel` location on the screen. This question is attempting to find the component at a `grid` location. There is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to access window(1,2) so that it would get Button 5.

Do some basic math.

You define your grid to have 3 columns.

So the index of your button would be:

```
int index = (row * columns) + column;
JButton button = b[index];
```

Where row = 1, and column = 2

Also:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    b[i] = new JButton("Button " + i);
    window.add(b[i]);
}
    
window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
```

1. you should set the layout BEFORE adding components to the panel.
2. You should use `new GridLayout(0, 3)` to specify you want to wrap after 3 column. That is is will wrap after 3 components no matter how many components you add to the grid